# Taking a screenshot of image in DIV with PHP

Tags: php, javascript

I have a website where users have designed their own product. I need a PHP function to generate an image/screenshot in JPG or PNG automatically from the designed product. The screenshot should be for the designed product by user. If it is a JavaScript utility (rather than PHP), that will be fine too.

I can't find anything. Where should I look?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912092/using-html5-canvas-javascript-to-take-screenshots/6678156#6678156

Answer (score 0):

Php is a server side language, it would need to be javascript. You could try this, however it may not be accurate.

http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/